# Does $E|X|<\infty$ and $E|Y|<\infty$ imply that $E|XY|<\infty$?

Tags: expected-value

Is this an intuitively clear but non-trivial result?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.  An easy counterexample is to have $X = Y$ and give them any distribution with finite mean but infinite variance.